# how can we remove the background color of the modal in bootstrap during fade in?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

When we click the button during the fade in the background color changes to light black as in picture? I just want the modal without any background effect (just the white portion without the black portion ) so how can we disable the background effect in the modal of bootstrap?

Comment: Please post your current code. Nobody can help you with just an image.

Answer (score 1):

From the bootstrap documentation found here http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/

> Options can be passed via data attributes or JavaScript. For data
>   attributes, append the option name to data-, as in data-backdrop=""
>
> backdrop {boolean or the string 'static'} default:true
>
> Includes a modal-backdrop element. Alternatively, specify static for a
>   backdrop which doesn't close the modal on click.

So just setting the option to `false` should do the trick as in

```
$('#myModal').modal({
  backdrop: false
});
```

Comment: Done, it was on the documentation page and without knowing the code from the user I wasn't sure posting an example sample would be informative or confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You have to decrease the opacity of backdrop.
Just override to below CSS class

```
.modal-backdrop, .modal-backdrop.fade.in{
opacity: 0.1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is css trick,we need to override the bootstrap css place the following code above your modal div,change id of the modal as per your id.

```
#myModal .modal-content{
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
border: none;
}
```